# ECS/Docker configuration for mapped volume

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS cluster which runs a task based on an Docker image. The task has run fine previously but since adding WORKDIR /app it's no longer running and has the following error:

```
python: can't open file './src/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I believe this is because I need to map a volume but am unsure where to specify that in my task definition.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install build-essential git-core \
                            tesseract-ocr poppler-utils libsm6 libxext6

...

# so that custom modules can be loaded from anywhere
ENV PYTHONPATH="/app:${PYTHONPATH}"

CMD ["python", "./src/main.py"]
```

Task Definition:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": null,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/dev-MYIMAGE",
          "awslogs-region": "REGION",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 1,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "ENVKEY",
          "value": "ENVVAL"
        },
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 12288,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "IMAGESRC",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "MYIMAGE"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "12288",
  "taskRoleArn": "ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "TASKDEF",
  "family": "dev-contract-extract",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.25"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.docker-plugin.local"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": null,
  "cpu": "1024",
  "revision": 5,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "host": null,
      "dockerVolumeConfiguration": {
        "autoprovision": true,
        "labels": null,
        "scope": "shared",
        "driver": "local",
        "driverOpts": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am fairly confident my error is something to do with the volume mapping.

Comment: Is there a `COPY` statement in your Dockerfile to copy your application code in?  You don’t show that.

Comment: @DavidMaze - I did experiment with adding COPY . /app on line 3 but no luck.

Comment: Docker has an [official tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) that's worth reading through.  You need to COPY your code into the image; you should not be trying to put your code in volumes, and in clustered environments like ECS doing that negates much of the advantage of using Docker.